# Array of doubles -- most frequent value method? (without hashmaps or sorting)

Tags: java, arrays, frequency

I have figured out how to create an array of integers and create a method to find the most frequent value in the array. Creating this method by creating another array used as a counter for each value. but how would I go about creating a method used to find the most frequent double in an array of DOUBLES.. without using hashmaps or sorting?

-this is my code for the method using integers, but will not work with double values/double array

```
public static int findMostFrequentValue(int[] array) {
    int i;
    int[] numberCount = new int[100];

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        ++numberCount[array[i]];

    int max = 0;
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < numberCount.length; j++) {
        if (numberCount[j] > max) max = j;
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: You realize you used a hash map for counting the ints, right? (Just not in the form of a `java.util.HashMap`.)

Comment: Your solution for ints will work if you know the max value stored in the array.  @arshajii is hinting at a general solution.

Comment: Use a TreeMap :) Or use an inner loop

Comment: Since you're dealing with doubles, you'll want a function to check "equality" within a tolerance.  The rest can then be done with either an inner loop or a hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick blurb, sticking to your requirement of no hashmaps or sorting.  Note, as coded, if there's a tie it returns the last match.  Also note this is <strike>exponential</strike> O(n^2) time with the inner loop, so poor for large arrays.

```
public class Frequency {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double[] array = {3.4, 6.8, 1.1, 2.4, 3.8, 6.8, 7.0, 5.0};
        double result = findMostFrequentValue(array);

        System.out.println("Most frequent value: " + result);
    }

    public static double findMostFrequentValue(double[] array) {
        int[] count = new int[array.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            count[i] = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (approxEquals(array[i], array[j], .0001)) {
                    count[i]++;
                }
            }
        }

        int index = 0;
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
            if (count[i] > max) {
                max = count[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }

        return array[index];
    }

    private static boolean approxEquals(double val1, double val2, double tolerance) {
        return Math.abs(val1 - val2) < tolerance;
    }

}
```

Comment: Only quadratic time, not exponential. Still not the best for large arrays, but the only solution that I could think of without "cheating" (that is, without manually sorting or building data structures that would resemble hash maps), so should be a +1

Comment: Yeah my bad I should've just written O(n^2) which was more obvious.